# added babel/present-react but error remains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm getting the following error

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

And I have tried both add the whole thing (first link) and add the plugin (second link) and that works just fine but I get the same error despite that.

This is my json file:

```json
{
  "name": "app2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^8.4.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.10.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), using the [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) template.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "jest": "^26.6.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This is the test file that is failing:

```js
const Login = require('./Login')
const { setActiveUser } = require('./userSlice')

test('login success', () =>{
    expect(Login()).toBe(<button/>)
})
```

What could be wrong?

Edit: I got a comment telling me to include babel config, the closest thing I find to that is the loadBabelConfij.js file:

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'loadPartialConfig', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _core().loadPartialConfig;
  }
});

function _core() {
  const data = require('@babel/core');

  _core = function () {
    return data;
  };

  return data;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide babel config?

Comment: I don't think I have a file like that, I even checked node-moduls